# Can I create an autocommand to be launched when I execute :update?

Tags: vim, autocommand

I would like to do some code reformatting whenever `:update` command is executed, is this possible?

I can't find any autocommand hook for updating, only for `:w` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:update` basically is *execute `:write` if buffer is modified, else do nothing*. The same `BufWritePre`  / `BufWrite` events apply to it (when the former case is true). That should be perfectly suitable for your reformatting trigger.

To only trigger on `:update`, but not on `:write` would require re-writing the `:update` command itself. For interactive use, that could be done via the [cmdalias.vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/cmdalias.vim), which allows redefinition of lowercase built-in commands.